# How do I reverse an array in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Suppose I have a long, unordered, and gradually growing column that I search the even numbers from.

```
=filter(A1:A,ISEVEN(A1:A)=TRUE)
```

Now I would like to reverse this result, so that the last even number in column A is listed first in the result. Many examples use helper columns or the `row` function, but that doesn't seem to be an option because you don't know how many even elements there are in this array before you begin. And even if I separately calculate that using `rows` I can't seem to figure it out. It seems like there should be a rather simple way to just "reverse" an array right?

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER({A1:A, ROW(A1:A)}, ISEVEN(A1:A), A1:A<>""), 2, 0),, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({A:A,ROW(A:A)},ISNUMBER(A:A),ISEVEN(A:A)),"Select Col1 Order By Col2 Desc")
```

Comment: I think your answer is the way to do it. I suppose more generally if you had an array rather than a range so you couldn't use the Row function, you would need to count the number of rows in the array and use Sequence(number_of_rows) to number the rows of the array.

Comment: Yes. I only had what the OP offered to go on, and he uses a real range in his original formula.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to delve into Apps Scripts (Extensions > Apps Scripts), you can use the JavaScript `Array.prototype.reverse()` function.

Paste this into your Apps Script code:

```
/**
 * Reverses range
 *
 * @param {Array} range The range of cells
 * @return The input range reversed
 * @customfunction
 */
function REVERSE(range) {
  return range.reverse();
}
```

Then use the formula in your cell as so:

```
=REVERSE(A1:A)
```

One advantage of this approach is that you then have a compact and reusable function that can be nested inside other formulas more easily.  However, I have not done any testing to see the performance impact of this solution in large sheets vs the more traditional formulas, so if you have a lot of data, you might want to check and see which works more efficiently for you.